# Admob causing Apple Mach-O Linker Error when trying to archive project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob

When project is working fine when I try to run in simulator. However, when I try to archive the project, I got the follow error. The code is too long. I just putting some part of it.

```
duplicate symbol l017 in:
    GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerAdViewDelegate.o)
    GoogleMobileAds(GADRewardBasedVideoAd+Mediation.o)
duplicate symbol l018 in:
    GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADCSITimeRecorder.o)
  GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADRewardBasedVideoAd+Mediation.o)
duplicate symbol l008 in:
    GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttributionView.o)
    GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADPushTransitionView.o)
duplicate symbol l014 in:
    GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADPinger.o)
    GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdAppViewController.o)
ld: 28 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159983/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-xcode-error
Check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by removing the "-ObjC" linker flag.